# How to add attachment into email with out downloading into Disk?

Tags: java

I have JAVA API through which i can send attachment, but i dont want to store content into disk and fetch, How can i add attachment into email with out downloading it into Disk ?

Here is how i tried it!

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String file = "http://example.com/2.pdf";
String fileName = "2.pdf"; 
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Thanks!

EDIT : Here `FileDataSource(file);` is expecting file from Disk not from URL!!

How Can i convert it?

Comment: And what goes wrong?  Please include your errors or failure explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply, Here I get FileNotFound Exception!

Comment: Then that is telling you that the link is wrong, try pulling it up in a browser by itself.

Comment: @Morantis No link is perfectly working! i have posted dummy URL here thats it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is a `DataSource` and you have a URL, try using `URLDataSource`:

```
DataSource source = new URLDataSource(file);
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot i was thinking there must some Very easy way of handling it!! You made my Day!!